# Python Unnest Comma Separated Values in List

Tags: python

I have the follwoing list:

`my_list = ['1', '7', '9, 11', '14']`

How do I unnest comma-separated items like so:

`new_list = ['1', '7', '9', '11', '14']`

Comment: I can't see the difference

Comment: 9 and 11 in the first list are the same item (separated by a comma), I would like to separate these out so 9 and 11 are separate items in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
    new_list += [a.strip() for a in x.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```
 new_list = [j.strip() for i in my_list for j in i.split(',')]
```